# Android tethering via bluetooth keeps disconnecting

Tags: connection-issues, bluetooth-tethering

I'm currently using a Google Nexus tablet tethered via Bluetooth to a Samsung S3 for internet.

Two things are annoying me.

First, if I take the phone away from the tablet (go out for lunch), the tablet disconnects and has to be manually reconnected. Is there a way to have that happen automatically?

Second, Bluetooth tethering, i.e. the internet sharing part needs to be switched on each time the bluetooth is switched on (or perhaps just after power cycling) on the S3. Is there no way to have that default to on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm doing the exact same thing, except with my Captivate, and I ran into the same problems. To solve them, I use three apps across the two devices. On my N7, I use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm5ldC5kaW5nbGlzY2guYW5kcm9pZC50YXNrZXJtIl0.) to detect when I lose wifi connection and use [Bluetooth Auto Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5teWtsb3MuYnRhdXRvY29ubmVjdCJd) as a Tasker plugin to automatically connect to my phone. On my phone, I use [Bluetooth Auto Tethering](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.refluxa.android.bat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImRlLnJlZmx1eGEuYW5kcm9pZC5iYXQiXQ..), which automatically turns on Bluetooth tethering when you start your phone.

As a bonus [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/txcv69kqvdan80b/bluetooth%20auto-toggle.xml) is a link to my Tasker profile/tasks which does all this stuff. I think you can just import it into your Tasker.

Comment: Importing the Tasker stuff worked for you?

Comment: going to work on it this evening and will let you know.